# How do I consume a JSon object that has no headers?

Tags: json, razor, model-view-controller, json.net

My C# MVC5 Razor page returns a Newtonsoft json link object to my controller (the "1" before \nEdit |" indicates that the checkbox is checked:

```
"{\"0\": [\"6146\",\"Kimball\",\"Jimmy\",\"General Funny Guy\",\"277\",\"Unite\",\"Jun 2019\",\"\",\"\",\"1\",\"\nEdit |\nDetails\n\n                \n\"],\"1\": [\"6147\",\"Hawk\",\"Jack\",\"\",\"547\",\"Painters\",\"Jun 2019\",\"\",\"\",\"on\",\"\nEdit |\nDetails\n\n                \n\"]}"
```

How do I parse this?

I am using a WebGrid to view and I want to allow the users to update only the lines they want (by checking the checkbox for that row), but it doesn't include an id for the 's in the dom. I figured out how to pull the values, but not the fieldname: "Last Name" , value: "Smith"... I only have the value and can't seem to parse it... one of my many failed attempts:

```
public ActoinResult AttMods(string gridData)
{

    dynamic parsedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(gridData);

                    foreach (var item in parsedArray)
                    {

                        string[] itemvalue = item.Split(delimiterChars);
                        {
                            var id = itemvalue[0];
                        }


                    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517217/how-to-consume-json-object-from-a-razor-page-that-has-no-headerids-in-c-sharp-m -- Here is a link to my full question, but I was hoping if I broke it down into smaller parts, someone would find it easier to help me get to an answer. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted this one out..If there is a more dynamic answer, please share... I'll give it a few days before I accept my own (admittedly clugy) answer.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {

        Dictionary <string,string[]> log = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(gridData);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string[]> keyValue in log)
        {
            if (keyValue.Value[9] == "1")//Update this row based on the checkbox being checked
            {
                var AttendeeID = keyValue.Value[0];
                int intAttendeeID = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(AttendeeID, out intAttendeeID))//Make sure the AttendeeID is valid
                {
                    var LName = keyValue.Value[1];
                    var FName = keyValue.Value[2];
                    var Title = keyValue.Value[3];
                    var kOrgID = keyValue.Value[4];
                    var Org = keyValue.Value[5];
                    var City = keyValue.Value[7];
                    var State = keyValue.Value[8];
                    var LegalApproval = keyValue.Value[9];


                    tblAttendee att = db.tblAttendees.Find(Convert.ToInt32(AttendeeID));
                    att.FName = FName;
                    att.LName = LName;
                    att.Title = Title;
                    att.kOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(kOrgID);
                    att.Organization = Org;
                    att.City = City;
                    att.State = State;
                    att.LegalApprovedAtt = Convert.ToBoolean(LegalApproval);
                }
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

You can avoid assigning the var's and just populate the att object with the KeyValue.Value[n] value, but you get the idea.